# Oracle to mysql database mirroring

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, mirroring

We are using ERP application that stores data to ORACLE database and also we have web applications that uses the same ERP database. We are getting the performance issues when ERP and another application use the same database.

We are planning to do mirroring of oracle database into mysql database. So that mysql db is used for web applications and oracle db is used for ERP. So we could say these new database (mysql) are mirror of ERP database.

What is the best way for mirroring this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Golden Gate for this kind op replication. See [GoldenGate for Oracle to MySQL](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:112:100189069462372%3a%3a%3a%3aP112_CONTENT_ID:5316&ei=qyN6UqyqGsvVsgaChIGICw&usg=AFQjCNGOV-wNaOQj6H9_eUj8vfBqQ3VU1A&sig2=GmFzvkFZLaji9OP0D_8u3g&bvm=bv.55980276,d.Yms)
A VERY smart alternative - and very price worthy - would be dbvisit replicate [The Dedicated Dbvisit Server : Replicating Data from Oracle to MySQL and SQL Server](http://blog.dbvisit.com/the-dedicated-dbvisit-server-replicating-data-from-oracle-to-mysql-and-sql-server/)