# How to compare 2 tables from 2 databases (and servers) different ? (Oracle & Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I want to compare 2 tables from 2 databases (and servers) different ... One is Oracle, the other is Mysql.

I did that for tables in the same DB like that :

```
SELECT FIELD 1, FIELD 2
FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME1
MINUS
SELECT FIELD 1, FIELD 2
FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME2
```

I'm using dbeaver for my queries.

Comment: There you are, now export to doc and meld or diff them docs.

Comment: If i export both tables to compare them via excel, the files are really (really) big (X00 000 lines). I would like to export the result of a query that compare the tables content.

Comment: can you try mirroring concept by this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805152/oracle-to-mysql-database-mirroring

Comment: Fortunately you wouldn't compare them via Excel. You would meld or diff them docs.

Comment: Mirroring is an overkill at this question.

Comment: Query you posted would work although there are two different DBMS's involved - create a **database link** (from Oracle to MySQL, for example).

Comment: @Littlefoot - is that easy to create a database link from Oracle to MySQL?

Comment: There is an article by Grégory Guillou on the Pythian blog which seems like it might be useful. [Check it out](https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/).

Comment: @APC, I don't use MySQL so I can't tell from my own experience, but Google says that *Heterogeneous Services* is the keyword. There are examples provided, so I suppose that it is *possible*. Is it easy? Well, not as if those were two Oracle databases, that's for sure.

Comment: @Littlefoot - Heterogeneous Services was what I was driving at. Configuring HS Gateways is not a simple task (or at least it wasn't the last time I had to do it, which to be fair was over a decade ago).

Comment: Maybe it is possible to create a database in local in order to copy paste all the tables i need to compare ? do you know if dbeaver allows to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` for equivalent logic:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2
FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME2 t2
                  WHERE t2.FIELD1 = t1.FIELD1 AND t2.FIELD2 = t2.FIELD2
                 );
```

Actually, this logic is not 100% equivalent.  On the other hand, it is standard syntax and should work in any database.

There are two important differences.

First, it returns duplicate value.  `MINUS` removes duplicates.

Second, it will filter out rows that have `NULL` values in either column.  If that is an issue, the comparison can be modified to take `NULL` values into account.

Another approach (that comes closer to `MINUS`) uses `UNION ALL` and aggregation:

```
select field1, field2
from ((select field1, field2, 1 as which
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select field1, field2, 2 as which
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by field1, field2
having max(which) = 1;
```

This handles `NULL` values and duplicates in the same way as `MINUS`.  It also easily generalizes to get other relationships between the two tables.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works for 2 tables in the same server, but if i want to compare tables in 2 different servers do you kow how to do that please ?

Comment: @Rifipop . . . Exactly the same.  You just need to link to the server so you can reference the table.  If that is your question, then you should ask a *new* question (after consulting the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from sch1.table1
minus
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from sch2.table1
```

is working well, but you have to do two more

```
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from sch2.table1
minus
select col1, col2, ..., coln
from sch1.table1
```

and

```
select count(*) ftom sch1.table1
union all
select count(*) ftom sch2.table1
```

And as you see that queries should be in the same RDBMS.